changing the row number of a pandas dataframe
I have the below dataframe:
    0-9 10-19   20-29   30-39   40-49   50-59   60-69   70-79   80-89   90-99   100-109 110-119
1   -692    -772    -741    -698    -707    -511    -371    -203    -95 -17 -8  -1.0
1   676 771 808 865 815 581 400 226 102 15  8   0.0

I want to change the row numbers to read Male and Female instead of 1 and 1.
I used the below code
index_labels = ['Male', 'Female']

# Create the DataFrame
Age_dist = pd.DataFrame(Age_dist, index=index_labels)
Age_dist

In the result I got, the values of my columns now read NaN.
    0-9 10-19   20-29   30-39   40-49   50-59   60-69   70-79   80-89   90-99   100-109 110-119
Male    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
Female  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

How do I fix this?

Simply assign to .index:
df.index = ["Male", "Female"]
print(df)

Prints:
        0-9  10-19  20-29  30-39  40-49  50-59  60-69  70-79  80-89  90-99  100-109  110-119
Male   -692   -772   -741   -698   -707   -511   -371   -203    -95    -17       -8     -1.0
Female  676    771    808    865    815    581    400    226    102     15        8      0.0


Input dataframe:
   0-9  10-19  20-29  30-39  40-49  50-59  60-69  70-79  80-89  90-99  100-109  110-119
1 -692   -772   -741   -698   -707   -511   -371   -203    -95    -17       -8     -1.0
1  676    771    808    865    815    581    400    226    102     15        8      0.0


Thank you.
Is there a way I can plot an age pyramid with it straight without having to manually build up a new dataframe?

you may have to transpose the dataframe and create a pyramid.
